# How to split a string containing of numbers separated by space into list of integers?

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

while doing many programs in python always i using write a block of code to split a string containing of numbers separated by space into list of integers

ex:
if we enter `1 2 3 4 5`, we should get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

is there any possibility to write the code in a single line

ex: `lst=input().split()`

if we use this i am getting list of strings in it.I need integers in it

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for some list comprehension.

`lst=[int(x) for x in input().split()]`

Comment: Remove the `.split()`, otherwise it would be one element.

Comment: @MendelG he specifically asked to input space separated integers as input. Without doing split, you cannot cast int on space separated items.